# Add a figure wrapper around img tag with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm finishing a migration of contents and I need to parse a lot of HTML to match the new structure.

I have a lot of images with inline styles, and I need to remove the styles adding a  wrapper around every tag.

This is my method:

```
  def convert_imgtag(html)
    html_body = Nokogiri::HTML::fragment(html)
    html_body.xpath('.//img').each do |img|

      ****

      img.xpath('.//@style').remove
    end
    html_body.to_html
  end
```

Where I add **** I need to add `<figure class="center-image"> </figure>` around my image tag. I try with the "wrap" method but is dowsn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think wrap only works on NodeSets. Try to split these changes in to two runs over the img-nodes.

```
html_body = Nokogiri::HTML::fragment(html)

nodes = html_body.xpath('.//img')
nodes.wrap('<figure class="center-image"> </figure>')
nodes.each do |img|
  img.xpath('.//@style').remove
end
```